# замена текста с определенной последовательностью

Tags: c#

Например, есть обычный текстовой документ на раб столе в котором есть числа от 0 до 100 построчно(1,2,3,...,99,100). А также есть другой txt док. в котором построчно записаны слова одинаковые, там, к примеру, слово «map». Вопрос: как через софт заменить это слово map(все строки которые только есть в док. на построчные числа из первого txt?

То есть результат должен быть таким:

```
static void map1() ->1  
static void map2() ->2  
...  
static void map100() ->100
```

По сути всю строку где есть слво `static void map_`и какая цифра заменить на 1,2,3....
То есть в итоге я получу построчную замену строке на число

Comment: Непонятно. Вот я нахожу, например, во втором файле `map3` и `map4`. А в первом есть только числа 1, 4 и 5. Что должно получиться на выходе?

Comment: не map3 и map4 a будет static void map_и число .....На выходе должно быть static void1(), static void4(), static void5()...То есть все строки в которых есть слово map("map" не "map4" а "map"), меняется на числа 1,4,5 ( эти числа записаны в тхт построчно и их кол-ство не 3 а   >3

Comment: то есть так должно быть:static void map()  
static void map()
...  
static void map()

берем числа из txt и будет:
static void 1()
static void 2()
...
static void 100()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, подойдёт вот что:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var replacements = File.ReadLines("1.txt");
    var inputLines = File.ReadLines("2.txt");
    var regex = new Regex(@"map(\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var outputLines = Replace(inputLines, regex, replacements);
    File.WriteAllLines("2_modified.txt", outputLines);
}

static IEnumerable<string> Replace(
    IEnumerable<string> haystack, Regex needle, IEnumerable<string> with)
{
    using (var it = with.GetEnumerator())
    {
        foreach (var s in haystack)
        {
            var result = s;
            foreach (Match match in needle.Matches(result).Cast<Match>().Reverse())
            {
                var group = match.Groups[1];
                if (!it.MoveNext())
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Недостаточно строк в первом файле");
                result = result.Substring(0, group.Index) +
                             it.Current +
                             result.Substring(group.Index + group.Length);
            }
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Для случая, когда файлов с заменами много, делаем так:

```
var replacementFiles = new[] { "1a.txt", "1b.txt" };
var replacements = replacementFiles.SelectMany(File.ReadLines);
```

и дальше по тексту.

Для конкретного каталога пойдёт, например,

```
var replacementDirectory = @"С:\";
var replacementFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(replacementDirectory, "*.txt");
```

(пути и маску нужно, разумеется, исправить).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37614/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-----).

Comment: @VladD коменты в чате

Comment: КТО-НИТЬ МОЖЕТ ПОДРЕДАКТИРОВАТЬ ОТВЕТ??